# Ubuntu multiple KDE sessions for same user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, kde

I have KDE on my Ubuntu and I have installed XRDP. I have `startkde` in my `.xsession` but I cannot login into it remotely unless I logout from it first.

The same is true vice-versa. If I logout and then connect using XRDP, I cannot login locally...

Is there any way I can stay logged in and remotely login with the same user?

-- EDIT --

I have a user that is always logged in on my NUC and is running a bunch of applications I need running 24/7. If I set that user to logout after 15 minutes (screen lock) I cannot access my applications (specifically, QBitTorrent Web UI).

I would also like to login to my NUC remotely so I setup OpenVPN and I am trying to login using XRDP. I can ofcourse access QBitTorrent Web UI, for an example, but I would sometimes like to install more applications.

My problem is that I cannot login using XRDP because the user is constantly logged in and running. Dropping a session would also make my applications unavailable after I logout from XRDP, wouldn't it?

Comment: You want to have two separate xrdp windows, with two separate ubuntu sessions running at the same time, but as the same user? Or do you want to "suspend" a session, then pick it up again later?

Comment: To be honest, I am a very basic Linux user so it is entirely possible I have a bad setup. I don't know WHAT I really wan't to do, but I know what is bothering me, so I put that in the question, hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the systemd linger setting, well more precisely, logind, so this might be helpful.

It sounds appropriate for your use-case, to run these as systemd services, at the user or system level, instead of needing a session, which serves as a user login environment and process namespace.

Write service files for your services!

See

- https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/
  or with more explanation
- https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/
  and many other stackexchange questions about how to write service files for your purposes. It's an essential skill that gets easier with time.

#### Running user processes (services*?) independent from session state (logged in/out)

From `man loginctl`:

```
   enable-linger [USER...], disable-linger [USER...]
       Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is
       spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run
       long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as argument. If no argument is specified,
       enables/disables lingering for the user of the session of the caller.

       See also KillUserProcesses= setting in logind.conf(5).
```

On systemd services started this way, [ArchWiki warns](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances):

`Warning: systemd services are not sessions, they run outside of logind. Do not use lingering to enable automatic login as it will break the session.`

It also talks about [killing users processes on logout](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Kill_user_processes_on_logout): how this breaks tmux/screen, which should be run differently, and `user@.service` will be killed when all user sessions are logged out unless lingering is enabled.

#### Running multiple sessions

Found some indication in:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/950595/multiple-parallel-sessions-as-a-single-user (the feature I'm looking for today, to try out a new WM in parallel)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/950535/what-are-parallel-sessions

which are bi-directionally linked.

More about remote login solutions, and relation to loginctl:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424071/multiple-loginctl-sessions-when-using-xrdp
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless/1409120#1409120